# Android app installation not asking for permissions defined in manifest with target level 21

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am using "targetSDKVersion" as 14. And "Project build target" as 21. Everything was working fine. I need to make some changes today and I found that my app is crashing when trying to read phone state. I checked the permissions given for my app. And found that there is no permission given.I was installing APK through eclipse. Then I tried to install APK through SD card and found that while installing app, its not asking for any permission.

Can someone help me out and make me understand why is this happening as I am not targeting marshmallow ?

Comment: Could you create a pastebin post of your manifest?

Comment: There is no "asking permission" in target 21.....runtime permissions are added since API23...or do you mean something else?